# I'm trying to dynamically select using python an image and use it on a website, is there a way for this to work?

Tags: python, html, flask

This is my python code-

```
file1 = '2D.jpg'
file2 = '3D.jpg'
s = f"""
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{file1}')}}" />
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{file2}')}}" />
"""
return render_template("index.html", s = s)
```

and my HTML using that varaible

```
<p>
    {{ s }}
</p>
```

instead of showing the image, as I would like, it just shows the html code I wrote. Any ideas for fixes? (I'm using Jinja2 if that helps)

Comment: Just add the template tag `safe` like this ` {{ s|safe }}` see [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#html-escaping) for more informations.

Comment: I've tried it before, it messes with the image file - GET /%7Burl_for('static',%20filename='3D.jpg')%7D HTTP/1.0

Comment: Are you using Jinja2?

Comment: Yes, I am using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach for generating HTML entities in your views then passing them to your templates is Flask/Jinja anti-pattern.

What this means, you need to seperate the logic between your backend (your views) and your rendered templates (Jinja part).

This is why when you apply `safe` filter in your template you'll endup to tell Jinja `Just show me this string as HTML and don't process it`. So, your entities that holds Jinja variables and methods are not well rendered.

So, an easy solution to your problem is to pass only the list of pictures you want to render and do the template logic in the template itself.

Here is a working example:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.views import MethodView

application = Flask(__name__)


class IndexView(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        filenames = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg']
        return render_template('index.html', filenames=filenames)


application.add_url_rule('/', view_func=IndexView.as_view('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
{% for filename in filenames %}
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=filename)}}" />
{% endfor %}
</body>
<html>
```

And when you load the app's website you'll have this HTML block:

```
<html>
<body>

    <img src="/static/file1.jpg" />

    <img src="/static/file2.jpg" />

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: 500: flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "application".

Comment: @Spylee01 Please run my example in a seperate project. It's a fully working example i've test it before posting it :-)

Comment: How can I change the app route from '/' , I get a 405 when i try it